# Webpack - compile handlebars and output html

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, handlebars.js

I'm starting out with webpack and already managed to get all my development setup in webpack. Only thing that left is compiling handlebars files and emitting static html files.
Specifically I want to watch for changes in any file in './src/templates/*.hbs' compile and emit html in './public/[name].html'.

Thanks for any advice.

*edit - couldn't figure out how to format code in comment so here it is

At the moment I'm trying HtmlWebpack plugin to load the .hbs template in and process it through handlebars-loader, but it only works for one file so I'm trying to find a way how to use it for all files in a folder.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    /* ... omitted Entry and output */
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                use: ['handlebars-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'My Test',
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'src/templates/index.hbs',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes, without knowing what you've done with Webpack config, it is difficult to fix your problem. Please post some more info of your code.

Comment: you have to call a new instance of HtmlWebpackPlugin for every single template file